# Bluetooth stops working after some time Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bluetooth, dualboot

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 330-15arr. I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed on the same SSD and I use grub2 for dualboot. My problem is that whenever I boot over from Windows, bluetooth works, but after like 2 minutes of mouse inactivity (i use a bluetooth mouse) it disconnects and all the settings connected to bluetooth stop working. Even a simple reboot won't make it work afterwards. The only solution is to boot back to Windows, use the bluetooth and boot back to Ubuntu. This is really annoying, since I have to boot back and forth while working.

EDIT: I don't know if it helps, but the output for the command "lsusb | grep -i bluetooth" is:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:c024 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
```

and for "dmesg | grep -i bluetooth" is:

```
[    1.710950] usb 3-2: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    3.423997] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.424044] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.424052] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.424056] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.424062] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.456962] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[    3.460052] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    3.460062] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[    3.472670] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[    3.475695] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 21678
[    4.064917] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x826ca99e
[    5.162895] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.162898] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.163043] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.453787] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   14.453803] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   14.453812] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 3279.007089] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2005 tx timeout
[ 3281.022837] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200b tx timeout
[ 3283.038968] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[ 3285.054821] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 3287.070848] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c3a tx timeout
[ 3287.070854] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3289.086806] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[ 3289.086813] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3291.102857] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2005 tx timeout
[ 3291.102863] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3293.118767] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200b tx timeout
[ 3293.118772] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3295.134755] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[ 3295.134761] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3297.150735] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 3297.150741] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3299.166735] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2005 tx timeout
[ 3299.166741] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3301.182804] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200b tx timeout
[ 3301.182810] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3303.198708] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[ 3303.198714] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3305.214690] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 3305.214696] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3307.230751] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2005 tx timeout
[ 3307.230757] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3309.246664] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200b tx timeout
[ 3309.246670] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3311.262649] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[ 3311.262654] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3313.278635] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 3313.278642] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3315.294625] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c52 tx timeout
[ 3315.294630] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3325.566545] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[ 3325.566550] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 3333.662747] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
```

Comment: I have this problem too in my HP Omen 15. Booting to windows fixes the problem. Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Same issue with same Linux version on HP Pavilion. Any news?